# Errors When Configuring Samba For Better MacOS Performance

Tags: macos, samba, smb

I've been following [this article](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_Samba_to_Work_Better_with_Mac_OS_X) to try optimize my samba setup for macOS and enable me to backup to it via TimeMachine.

Implementing the suggestions at the bottom of the article I'm still able to read from my share and copy data too it but am unable to create new folders or rename existing ones. As seen in the screenshot I'm given this error when trying to create a folder called "hello" but it reverts to "untitled folder". The folder is actually created and exists the remote share but the name doesn't stick.

[image: Error code when trying to create folder]

I get another error when trying to delete the folder which can be seen in the image below.

[image: Error when trying to delete folder]

If I try to copy over a text file on its own as seen in the screenshot below I receive a different error. The file is copied over and retains its name but the contents are lost.

[image: Error trying to copy over a file]

If I place that same file in a folder and copy the whole folder over there is no error and both the folder and file retain their names and the file retains its contents.

However, if I try to delete this folder containing the text file I am confronted with the error found below. I have checked the file and it is not locked and my current user has read-write permissions (as seen in finders get info).

[image: Error when deleting folder containing file]

Here is my current smb.conf file:

```
[Global]
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
logging = file
server role = standalone server
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccefully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
min protocol = SMB2
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
fruit:metadata = stream
fruit:model = RackMac
fruit:veto_appledouble = no
fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes

[Media]
path = /mnt/hdd2tb/Media
writeable = yes
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr

[Time Machine]
path = /mnt/hdd2tb/Backup
writeable = yes
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
fruit:time machine = yes
fruit:time machine max size = 1T
```

I've found that if I remove streams_xattr from the vfs objects field under my Media share it fixes all these issues but read [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_fruit.8.html) that it must be in the vfs stack in order for the fruit module to work.

I thought this might be a permission issue so ran `sudo chmod -R 777 hdd2tb` on my server which is the directory that I have my hard drive mounted. The effects of this can be seen below.

[image: Folder permissions after chmod]

I've run out of ideas at this point so would be super grateful for any input, I'd really like to get this working.

Comment: There's some conflicting sentences, it makes it hard to understand what you actually want.  Do you want Time Machine to backup via SMB to the Media share? If not, why does it matter if `streams_xattr` is on Media or not?

Comment: @jnovack I have the Media share for my movies and stuff which I would also like to be optimized for mac which is why I have the vfs objects listed there also. Then I have the Time Machine share which is defined as a separate share with a size limit which I would like to use exclusively for backups via SMB. Does the make sense or clarity things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by reformatting my hard drive to ext4 because it supports extended attributes which I wasn't aware of.